# Optimal way to create mongo documents with a ttl and disk i/o in mind

Tags: php, performance, mongodb, ttl, disk-io

What's the best strategy for using a TTL index in Mongo DB taking into account the disk i/o ratio.

### *Preface*:

I work on a clustered mongodb (v2.*) infrastructure where each node has about 1TB of hard disk.
In there logging information are save for a period of 7 days. After that time they are not needed and should be deleted. There are 6 databases with 10 collections each and more than 10million documents per collection. Let's assume that we are storing 100GB of temporary data each day.

Therefore I created a simple index on the createdAt field.

```
  db.my_collection.ensureIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 604800, background : true });
```

This will delete all documents inserted into this collection 7 days after the timestamp that was put into `createdAt`. This is clear to me. But I'm unsure on how to create the documents that will be saved into the collection.

The mongo docs for background indexes state:

```
The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60 seconds.
```

### *Question*:

What's the best way to create that TTL index when also thinking about the future deletion.

e.g.
Here are 3 ways we can create the objects to be saved. The syntax I used is php but that doesn't matter.

**Option 1:**

```
   'createdAt' => new MongoDate(strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))
```

In here all documents created today will be save with creation time of e.g. "2015-04-09 00:00:00".
This means all documents will be "expired" on "2015-04-16 00:00:00".

Pro:

- Every day shortly after midnight the diskusage should drop by 100GB.
- You can easily see if there's and error. If there is no drop in diskusage something went wrong.

Cons:

- Deleting 100GB of data will result in huge disk io and possibly slow down other processes.
- The documents are save less than exactly 7 days du to the missing hours and minutes.

**Option 2:**

```
   'createdAt' => new MongoDate(strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s')))
```

In here all documents created will have a different creation time of e.g. "2015-04-09 13:23:45".
This means this sample document will be "expired" on "2015-04-16 13:23:45".

Pro:

- The documents are saved exactly 7 days.
- The disk io will be nearly constant over the whole day. The possibility of interfering with other processes is smaller.

Cons:

- Seeing if there's an error is not as easy as option 1, as the documents will be deleted through out the day.
  There will be no huge jump in disk usage.

**(Option 3):**

I think this should be the same as option 2. Nevertheless I wanted to mention it here.

We could also change the index to not expire after a specific amount of time but at a specific date.

```
db.my_collection.ensureIndex( { "deleteAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0, background : true });
```

And then create the object this way:

```
'deleteAt' => new MongoDate(strtotime("+7 days")),
```

---

What do you think is the best possibility? Did anyone had experience with such a problem/infrastructure ? I would love to get some feedback from experienced mongodb developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Disclaimer***: I am by no means a PHP developer, so I can not give you any PHP code.

The problem here is that you want to delete all data at the beginning of the day. So when the TTL task runs for the first time after 00:00, it tries to remove all the documents, as you have written

However, your assumptions are not quite precise. If a log entry was made today at 16:00, the exact expiration date with a one week retention (604800 seconds) would be Thursday, April 16th 2015 **at 16:00**.

So the easiest way to spread the disk IO over the 1440 runs of the TTL background process is to not only use the date as a reference, but the time, too.

However, it may well be possible that you want to *display* only the entries for the last six days plus today's. That's easily achievable using by limiting the results in the queries. Given a document structure like

```
{
  _id: <SomeObjectId>,
  entry: "Something happened!"
  createdAt: ISODate("2015-04-02T09:11:27.038Z")
}
```

You would be able to select all relevant entries as easy as

```
db.logentries.find({createdAt:{$gt:ISODate("2015-04-03T00:00:00.000Z") } })
```

which would return all entries from six days ago from now plus today's. Obviously, you have to do some date calculations in this case.

Comment: Thanks very much, I wasn't looking for any php code. Just some thoughts and ideas.
What you suggest sounds good and encouraged me in my thinking. I'll be switching to a TTL that includes minutes and seconds.